# Golang how to return list in gRPC

Tags: go, grpc

I have two structures. One own, and the other generated through gRPC. The problem is that when you try to return your own through gRPC, an error is generated: "cannot use list (variable of type []db.User) as *pb.UsersList value in return statement"
How can I convert [db.User in *pb.UserList?
[]User

```
type User struct{
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}
```

gRPC UsersList:

```
type UsersList struct {
    state protoiml.MessageState
    sizeCache protoiml.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoiml.UnknownFields
    User []*User `protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=user,proto3" json:"user,omitempty
}
```

Comment: *cannot use list (variable of type []db.User*  but you have type **[]*User**  - slice of pointers but you try to put there slice of User structures. **[]User**

Comment: I understand it. The question is how can one convert from one structure to another

Comment: use **for range loop**

Comment: cannot use u (variable of type db.User) as *pb.UsersList value

Answer (score 1):

`[]db.User` and `*pb.UsersList` are different types and you cannot just return one as the other (for a start one is a slice the other a pointer to a struct). You will need to convert with something like this ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/JqgvqrQMwgB)):

```golang
func convert(in []User) *PbUsersList {
    pbU := make([]*PbUser, len(in))
    for i := range in {
        pbU[i] = &PbUser{User: in[i].Username, Pass: in[i].Password}
    }
    return &PbUsersList{User: pbU}
}
```

*Note: To demonstrate this I have put both structures in `main` in your real code `[]User` would be `[]db.User` and `*PbUsersList` would be `*UsersList`.*